# Service Registration and Discovery Eureka Server start up issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am getting the following error while trying to start the eureka server.The apache commons config lib is showing in the maven lib section on the project.
Have tried using the same pom file as given in the following URL
https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.initEurekaEnvironment(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerBootstrap.contextInitialized(EurekaServerBootstrap.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration$1.run(EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration.java:71) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
```

I am attaching the pom.xml which I am using

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>eureka-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.M8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Is this due to some missing dependencies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could very well be due to apache `commons-configuration` missing or incompatible transitive dependency.

- I would suggest you analyze the dependency tree using `mvn:dependency
  tree` and identify the `commons-configuration` version.
- You might want to explicitly add the latest maven
  `commoins-configuration` in your pom

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
>     <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
>     <version>1.9</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Thanks,the was resolved when I added the commons-configuration 1.9 in pom file.earlier had 1.8 in the classpath.